# Selenium on server

Tags: python, django, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm quite new to whole Selenim thing and I have a simple question.

When I run tests (Django application) on my local machine, everything works great. But how this should be done on server? There is no X, so how can I start up webdriver there? What's the common way?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you run the tests on your server? Tests are for running in development, or continuous integration.

Comment: I was thinking that running tests against stagging (dev code + production database) is a common thing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a continuous integration solution like Jenkins to run your tests periodically.

Comment: Thanks I will check that out.